# Dynamic Checkbuttons in Python

Tags: python, dynamic, checkbox, runtime

I have to implement 5 to 6 checkbuttons next to each other at run time. The checkboxes are generating but when i deselect any one of them, the rest get deselected too. Also, another thing if i want is , if the text attribute of a checkbutton is repeated, it should line up at the same place as where it was and not create a new checkbutton.

the only code i have for the checkbutton is this

```
option2 = Checkbutton(self.controls,text = name,
variable = self.variable,command lambda:display_temperature(self.variable,name))
```

option2.pack(side = 'left', anchor = 'sw', pady = 10, padx = 10)
   self.controls.pack()

Comment: Is the exact same code used for all checkbuttons? do they all have the same name? It's likely that the way the buttons have been stored has tricked Python into thinking they are all the same thing, so by deselecting one, it is effecitvely seen as deselecting all of them.

Comment: Yes....the checbuttons are generated at run time....even the text attribute is ddynamic....this is the only piece of code which generates checkbuttons.

Answer (score 0):

If all the checkbuttons have the same name and are attached to the same variable, python won't be able to distinguish between them.

Comment: It's difficult with what you've given, I can't replicate your code without having all the dependencies (self.controls, name, self.variable, display_temperature etc.).